# MySQL. Многие ко многим

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте, коллеги!

Есть таблицы: users (user_id, user_name); group (group_id, group_title) и user_group (user_id, group_id).

Задача: вывести список юзеров и групп, к которым они относятся (один юзер может находиться в 0-N количестве групп).

```
Иван (Группа1, Группа2...); 
Степан (Группа2, Группа3...).
```

Насколько это реально сделать одним запросом? Пока только в состоянии получить стандартный список с обычными JOIN'ами, а в php уже собирать массив как нужно и отправлять во вьювер.

```
SELECT `users`.*, `group`.* FROM `user_group` 
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `user_group`.`user_id`=`users`.`user_id` 
LEFT JOIN `group` ON `user_group`.`group_id`=`group`.`group_id`;
```

Comment: `SELECT `users`.*, `group`.* 
FROM `users` u
LEFT JOIN `user_group` ug 
 ON `ug`.`user_id`=`u`.`user_id` 
LEFT JOIN `group` g
 ON `ug`.`group_id`=`g`.`group_id`;`

Comment: eсли надо выводить все пользователей то начинай с него,А не наоборот.Ну или второй `LEFT JOIN` заменить `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` ом

Comment: Спасибо, но Ваш вариант ничего по сути не изменил =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT u.user_name, GROUP_CONCAT(g.group_title) groups
FROM       users      u
LEFT JOIN  user_group ug ON ug.user_id  = u.user_id
LEFT JOIN `group`     g  ON ug.group_id = g.group_id
GROUP BY u.user_name;
```

Comment: Супер! Попробую остальные предложенные варианты. Но этот мне уже более чем подходит. Благодарю!

Comment: @Andrey, [Почему так важно принимать участие в оценке вопросов и ответов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)